# How to combine common dates into 1 row in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, row

My query is:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM CO.ORDER_DATE) "DATE",
       TO_CHAR(CO.ORDER_DATE, 'DY') "BUSIEST DAY",
       SUM(OLI.QUANTITY) "NO. OF DISHES"
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER CO INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE_ITEM OLI
ON CO.ORDER_ID = OLI.ORDER_ID
WHERE CO.ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
AND CO.ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
GROUP BY CO.ORDER_DATE
ORDER BY CO.ORDER_DATE
```

My current output is:

```
DATE   BUSIEST DAY    NO. OF DISHES
-----------------------------------
1      SUN            27
1      SUN            10
14     SAT            10
```

The output I want is:

```
DATE   BUSIEST DAY    NO. OF DISHES
-----------------------------------
1      SUN            37
14     SAT            10
```

What changes do I need to make in my Oracle SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that while you are selecting the day of the month, you are actually aggregating by the date.  This means that two different dates on the first of the month would end up appearing as two separate records.  You should instead aggregate by the actual day value and busiest day values:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM CO.ORDER_DATE) "DATE",
    TO_CHAR(CO.ORDER_DATE, 'DY') "BUSIEST DAY",
    SUM(OLI.QUANTITY) "NO. OF DISHES"
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER CO
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE_ITEM OLI
    ON CO.ORDER_ID = OLI.ORDER_ID
WHERE
    CO.ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY') AND
    CO.ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM CO.ORDER_DATE),
    TO_CHAR(CO.ORDER_DATE, 'DY')
ORDER BY
    "DATE";
```

Comment: I am getting an error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Well I don't see anything wrong with my code, and without sample data/demo, I can't test it further.

Comment: I think the issue with `order by` it can not contain the column `CO.ORDER_DATE`. Instead, you can use `"DATE"` in `order by` clause --> `order by "DATE"`

Comment: Yes, it is working now. That ORDER BY "DATE" made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a time component in your "date".  This is hidden in Oracle.  I would actually recommend that you return the full date -- it makes it easier to expand the query across multiple months.

So:

```
SELECT TRUNC(CO.ORDER_DATE) as DATE,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CO.ORDER_DATE), 'DY') as BUSIEST_DAY,
       SUM(OLI.QUANTITY) as Num_Dishes
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER CO INNER JOIN
     ORDER_LINE_ITEM OLI
     ON CO.ORDER_ID = OLI.ORDER_ID
WHERE CO.ORDER_DATE >= DATE '2019-09-01' AND
      CO.ORDER_DATE < DATE '2019-10-01'
GROUP BY TRUNC(CO.ORDER_DATE)
ORDER BY TRUNC(CO.ORDER_DATE);
```

Note that this also changes the `WHERE` clause.  This will include *all* data in September, including orders during the day on Sep 30th.  I strongly recommend using these comparisons rather than `BETWEEN` when working with dates -- precisely because this logic works with and without time components.

Comment: I tried this, but I don't understand why I am getting an error " ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @SamVitare . . . There was an extra closing paren.

Comment: Where is the extra parenthesis. I am unable to notice it.

Comment: I am able to run this code with the following changes:  `SELECT` `TRUNC(CO.ORDER_DATE) AS "DATE",`
       `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CO.ORDER_DATE), 'DY') AS "BUSIEST DAY",` 
       `SUM(OLI.QUANTITY) as "Num_Dishes"`
`FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER CO INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE_ITEM OLI` 
 `ON CO.ORDER_ID = OLI.ORDER_ID`
`WHERE CO.ORDER_DATE >= DATE '2019-09-01' AND` 
      `CO.ORDER_DATE < DATE '2019-10-01'` 
`GROUP BY TRUNC(CO.ORDER_DATE)`
`ORDER BY "DATE";`